# How to find min and max value from a list that is passed on to a function as argument? I want to find min and max of list but not getting the output

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, max

*#Function to find out maximum and minimum marks
#From a list input, then passed as an argument into the function *

```
def marks(*args):
    print(args)
    print(max(args))
    print(min(args))

#marks input
mymarks = list(map(int,input("Enter the marks of all subjects: ").split()))
**#function call**
marks(mymarks)

Output:
Enter the marks of all subjects: 67 77 89 56 40
([67, 77, 89, 56, 40],)
[67, 77, 89, 56, 40]
[67, 77, 89, 56, 40]
```

Comment: Do you want the user to enter the list manually? Or enter it as a list parameter?

Comment: I want the user to enter manually, then the code will automatically convert the input into a list.

Comment: Do you know what `*args` does? It means that all positional arguments will be passed in as a single tuple, which you then need to unpack. In your case, it will be a tuple containing a single list of numbers. The simple fix is to remove `*args`, and to accept a single list parameter, `numbers` for example.

Comment: While the function takes n arguments, you are passing 1 argument of type list. You will need to unpack the list such as `marks(*mymarks)` or change the method to `def marks(arg)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, but you make the entering of `mymarks` more complicated than needed.

Instead of using `*args`, just use plain args. And instead of the `map`, just call `split()` on the input value. `split` already returns a list.

```
def marks(args):
    print(args)
    print(max(args))
    print(min(args))


# marks input
mymarks = input("Enter the marks of all subjects: ").split()
marks(mymarks)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `*args` declare a variable like `def marks(m)` or use `args[0]`.

Declaring variable will be the best as you can then just use `max(m)` to get the max value in list.

Your function sets max of args which is a tuple. Your list is inside that tuple.

Happy coding.